# Insert Data Attribute Value Into Iframe src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a number buttons which when pressed open a modal with an `iframe`. The buttons have data attributes that store the link which I want to pass to the `iframe` `scr`.

This is the code for the buttons:

```
<a href="#myModal" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-jobid="index.php?/job/view/1" ><strong>View</strong></a>

<a href="#myModal" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-jobid="index.php?/job/view/2" ><strong>View</strong></a>

<a href="#myModal" style="float: right;" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-jobid="index.php?/job/view/3" ><strong>View</strong></a>
```

This is the code for the iframe:

```
<iframe style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none;" src=""></iframe>
```

My question is how can I pass the `data-jobid` to the `src` of the `iframe` each time one of the buttons is clicked?

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted this?  I don't see anything wrong with how the question was phrased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hook a `click` handler to the `.btn-outline-secondary` elements, then read the `data()` attribute from them before setting the `src` attribute of the `iframe`, like this:

```
$('.btn-outline-secondary').click(function() {
  $('iframe').attr('src', $(this).data('jobid'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, I learned something new today.  I never realized  `$(this).data('jobid')` is the same as `$(this).attr('data-jobid')`.

Comment: Glad it helped you :) Also, just FYI, they're not quite the same. `attr()` reads the attribute from the DOM, whereas `data()` reads it from jQuery's internal cache. So long as you use the same method to get/set the value it's fine. Personally I prefer `data()` as it's faster in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via jQuery like this:

```
$(".btn")click(function(){
var data = $(this).attr('data-jobid');
$(iframe).attr('src', data);
});
```